# How to save what I checked on a radio button in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to save what I checked on a radio button, but when I close the view and come back, the radio but have nothing checked, but when I am looking into the Core Data database, what I checked appears in database.

Short story : The radio button works well, but if I exit and come back, nothing is check, but is succesfully saved in db.

This is My Radio Button Field.

```
struct RadioButtonField: View {
    let id: Int
    let label: String
    let size: CGFloat
    let img : String
    let color: Color
    let textSize: CGFloat
    let isMarked:Bool
    let callback: (Int)->()
    init(
        id: Int,
        label:String,
        img : String,
        size: CGFloat = 20,
        color: Color = Color.colorGrayDark,
        textSize: CGFloat = 16,
        isMarked: Bool = false,
        callback: @escaping (Int)->()
    ) {
        self.id = id
        self.label = label
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.textSize = textSize
        self.isMarked = isMarked
        self.callback = callback
        self.img = img
    }
    var body: some View {
        Button(action:{
            callback(id)
        }) {
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                Image(img, bundle: Bundle.main)
                Text(label)
                    .font(Font.system(size: textSize))
                Spacer()
                Image(self.isMarked ? "checkboxSelected" : "checkboxUnselected")
                    .renderingMode(.original)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: self.size, height: self.size)
                //                    Spacer()
            }.foregroundColor(self.color)
        }   
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    }    
}
```

---

This is my " RadioButtonGroups " view :

```
struct RadioButtonGroups: View {
    let callback: (Int) -> ()
    @State var selectedId: Int = 0
    @EnvironmentObject var syncViewModel : SyncViewModel
    @ObservedObject var coreDataViewModel = CoreDataViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(syncViewModel.paymentMethod) { payment in
            RadioButtonField(id: payment.id, label: payment.text, img: "cash",isMarked: selectedId == payment.id && selectedId == coreDataViewModel.savedDetails.first?.paymentMethod ?? 0  ? true : false, callback: radioGroupCallback)
        }
    }
    func radioGroupCallback(id: Int) {
        selectedId = id
        callback(id)
    }
}
```

---

This is how Radio Button is called in the View :

```
struct LivrareView: View {
    @StateObject var coreDataViewModel = CoreDataViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            RadioButtonGroups { selected in
                coreDataViewModel.savedDetails.first?.paymentMethod = Int16(selected)
                coreDataViewModel.saveContext()
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

If anyone can help me, how can I make this work ?

Comment: You haven't shown the relevant code for `CoreDataViewModel` or `SyncViewModel`, which are likely integral to this issue.

Comment: Get rid of the view model and use @FetchRequest

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70869061/swiftui-how-to-fetch-core-data-values-from-detail-to-edit-views/70901886#70901886

Comment: @4265756b69 I wonder have you ever solved this?