# I create an object in a view, how do I pass this object to child views as an ObservedObject?

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I am trying to create a Recpipe object (CoreData entity) and then pass that object to a ChildView after it's created. What's the best way to do this?

My first attempt was to create a @StateObject in the MainView and then pass that to ChildViews as an @ObservedObject, but this seems to only work great for objects that already exist. The @StateObject is a 'get only' property so I can't modify it based on the function return. Perhaps I don't really want to create a @StateObject in this circumstance?

```
struct MainView: View {
    
    @State private var presentChildView: Bool = false
    @StateObject private var recipe: Recipe = Recipe()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            NavigationLink(destination: ChildView(recipe: recipe), isActive: $presentChildView) {
                EmptyView()
            }

            Button("Action", action: {
                recipe = functionThatReturnsRecipe()
                presentChildView = true
            })
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var recipe: Recipe
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(recipe.title)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [swiftui how to fetch core data values from Detail to Edit views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70869061/swiftui-how-to-fetch-core-data-values-from-detail-to-edit-views)

Comment: You are initializing the CoreData object improperly `Recipe()` won't work. The answer I linked above has a sample. See the `FileAdd` `View` in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you hold the object in `@State` or even better inside a struct to hold all the `ChildView`'s related vars so it can be tested independently, e.g.

```
struct ChildViewConfig {
    var recipe: Recipe?
    var isPresented = false
    
    mutating func present(viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        recipe = Recipe(context: viewContext)
        isPresented = true
    }

    // might have other save or dismiss mutating funcs here.
}

struct MainView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @State private var config = ChildViewConfig()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Present") {
                config.present(context: viewContext)
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $config.isPresented, onDismiss: nil) {
            ChildView(recipe: config.recipe!)
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var recipe: Recipe
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(recipe.title)
    }
}
```

[This answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70871714/259521) uses the more advanced `.sheet(item:onDismiss)` that you may prefer because is designed for this use case of editing an item and allows for the use of a child context scratch pad because when setting the item to nil means the `item.childContext` will be discarded if the editing in the sheet is cancelled.

Learn more about this `@State` `Config` struct pattern at [4:18 in Data Essentials in SwiftUI (WWDC 2020)](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10040/?time=253)

Comment: I thought that @State wrappers should be limited to simple data types and avoided for custom classes and structures?

Comment: @ChristianStevenson Any value type such as a `struct` or `enum` can be used with `@State`

Comment: I added a link in the answer to a WWDC video that explains the @State custom struct pattern for editor view configs.

Answer (score 0):

You can have instead some concept of app state or manager (anything represented business logic) which would hold/update your recipes, like

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var recipe: Recipe = Recipe()

    func refreshRecipe() {
        self.recipe = functionThatReturnsRecipe()    // << now works !!
    }

    private func functionThatReturnsRecipe() -> Recipe {
        Recipe()
    }
}

struct MainView: View {

    @State private var presentChildView: Bool = false
    @StateObject private var appState = AppState()      // << non-changeable

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            NavigationLink(destination: ChildView(recipe: appState.recipe), isActive: $presentChildView) {
                EmptyView()
            }

            Button("Action", action: {
                appState.refreshRecipe()
                presentChildView = true
            })
        }
    }
}
```