# ToolbarItem button adds an object, but view is not refreshed

Tags: swift, swiftui

Main screen (simplified):

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Board.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    var fetchedBoards: FetchedResults<Board>
    @State private var boards: [Board] = []
    @State private var selectedBoard: Board?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            BoardsNavigationListView(boards: $boards, selectedBoard: $selectedBoard)
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup {
                Button(
                    action: addTaskList,
                    label: { Image(systemName: "plus") }
                )
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            boards = fetchedBoards.map({b in b as Board})
            if (boards.first != nil) {
                selectedBoard = boards.first!
            }
        }
    }

    private func addTaskList() {
        if (selectedBoard == nil) { return }
        let newTaskList = factory.newTaskList(context: viewContext, board: selectedBoard!)

        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            self.error = AppError.SaveFailed
            selectedBoard!.removeFromLists(newTaskList)
        }
    }
}
```

All changes in `BoardsNavigationListView` gets refreshed. However, when I add a new `TaskList` from this screen, no change is detected, no matter what I try (using boolean refresh, objectWillChange, ....)

What am I missing? Do you also see something wrong with this main view?

Comment: Get rid of the boards array just use the fetch request. Nothing is reloading this second array.

Comment: But I am using it as a @State and bind it in child view. When I don't do that, my child's view is not getting updated.

Comment: State is a source of truth it has no connection with FetchResults that actually knows there is a change. Why are you binding to that array? It doesn’t make sense…. There is no reason to bind to a core data array when you are using the fetch results wrapper. There isn’t a valid use case.

Comment: All CoreData objects are ObservableObjects/reference type. Since the objects already exist in the FetchResults wrapper you just need the child object wrapped in ObservedObject. Binding is for value types not reference types. The only way to affect the store is via the context binding to an array as no effect on the store.

Comment: See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70869061/swiftui-how-to-fetch-core-data-values-from-detail-to-edit-views/70901886#70901886

Comment: @loremipsum please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73562752/update-on-observedobject-not-refreshed - not sure what I am doing wrong. Now everything works except adding/updating the last elements in the model graph.