# Update on @ObservedObject not refreshed

Tags: swiftui

Board view:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct BoardView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @ObservedObject var board: Board // works fine    
    @State private var newTask: Task?

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            let taskLists = Arrays.of(taskLists: board.lists)
            ForEach(taskLists, id: \.self) { list in
                VStack {
                    ScrollView {
                        LazyVStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(list.title ?? "")
                            TasksView(taskList: list)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And `TaskView` is simple:

```swift
struct TasksView: View {
    @ObservedObject var taskList: TaskList
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        let tasks = Arrays.of(tasks: taskList.tasks)
        ForEach(tasks, id: \.self) { task in
            Text(task.name ?? "")
            Button(
                action: { task.name = "XXXX"
                   try? viewContext.save()
                },
                label: { Image(systemName: "arrow.triangle.swap")}
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Statics in `Arrays` (just one func, but you get the point):

```swift
static func of(tasks: NSSet?) -> [Task] {
    Array((tasks as? Set<Task>)?.sorted(by: sortByCreated) ?? [])
}
```

Why clicking on the button DOES NOT refresh the view? What am I missing?

Comment: You aren’t observing the task, every ObservableObject needs to be wrapped. You also got rid of the fetch results. You aren’t listening to the store now

Comment: as you can see `let taskLists = Arrays.of(taskLists: board.lists)` is not declared as an `ObservedObject`.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine an array can’t be an ObservedObject. The resulting task from the loop can be.

Comment: my point was, in `TasksView` there is: `@ObservedObject var taskList: TaskList`, but 
`let taskLists = Arrays.of(taskLists: board.lists)` is declared in `BoardView` is not.
But you are right, the OP code is so bad it makes no sense.

Comment: @loremipsum I believe I am getting what you are saying; thank you! However, I am not sure what to do. I have a model collection with a depth of 3: Board -> Lists -> Tasks. Not sure how I can bind everything together :((( I am not getting how to iterate with ForEach and not converting to an array.

Comment: forget about binding anything that isn’t a variable of the object. There is no such thing as binding to an array of core data objects. Wrap every core data object with ObservedObject this is very simple stuff that you are over complicating. When you have an NSet just use Array(object.setVariable)

Comment: You have to wrap every object within the array too in the subview

Comment: @loremipsum got it. But I am not sure how to iterate with ForEach and then wrap with ObservedObject. I am searching the net, and finding all bunch of information but nothing really works at the end. I even create a single view with 3 nested ForEach, and it behaves the same :( Do I need to have an inner view in order to wrap an element? Or I can wrap it before passing to the view?

Comment: Cool, got it. Wrapping with ObservedObject == create new view. Need to extract ForEach out from the view, i.e. parent iterates childs; its not that child view iterates.

Comment: No ForEach == ListView, then you make RowView and/or DetailView